# Pass variables by reference to dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

I want to accomplish the following thing:

I have a Class X, and many different other classes (A,B,C, ...).
Class X has a method, with which all other classes can publish some of their variables to Class X.

In class X, I want to collect all these variables in a dictionary.

**I want that dictionary to always have the current value of the variables which were passed by another class, *without publishing the specific variable from the other class again*.**

Example:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}

    def add_to_dict(self, var_name, var):
        # obviously this is the point, where it fails - I want somehow that a 
        # reference to var gets added to the dict, and not just a copy of var
        self.d[var_name] = var   


class A:
    def __init__(self, instance_of_X):
        self.var = 5    # variable which gets updated regularly within A
        self.instance_of_X = instance_of_X

    def publish(self):
        # I want all value changes of var to also be present in X, without
        # updating it by myself
        self.instance_of_X.add_to_dict('var_name', self.var)
```

Comment: You can only have references to objects in Python. You can't have references to variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have references to variables like that in Python. However, it's possible to simulate the effect by keeping track of the object and the attribute name of interest, and use that in conjunction with a `@property` descriptor to invokes a function that will retrieve the current value of the attributes when they're needed.

Here's what I mean:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self._d = {}

    def add_to_dict(self, alias, obj, attr_name):
        self._d[alias] = lambda: getattr(obj, attr_name)  # Function to retrieve attr value.

    @property
    def d(self):
        return {alias: get_obj_attr() for alias, get_obj_attr in self._d.items()}


class A:
    def __init__(self, instance_of_X):
        self.var = 5  # Variable which gets updated regularly within A.
        self.instance_of_X = instance_of_X

    def publish(self):
        self.instance_of_X.add_to_dict('var_alias', self, 'var')


x = X()
a = A(x)
a.publish()
print(x.d)  # -> {'var_alias': 5}
a.var = 42
print(x.d)  # -> {'var_alias': 42}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}

    def add_to_dict(self, var_name, var):
        # obviously this is the point, where it fails - I want somehow that a
        # reference to var gets added to the dict, and not just a copy of var
        self.d[var_name] = var


class A:
    def __init__(self, instance_of_X):
        self.var = 5    # variable which gets updated regularly within A
        self.instance_of_X = instance_of_X

    def publish(self):
        # I want all value changes of var to also be present in X, without
        # updating it by myself
        self.instance_of_X.add_to_dict('var_name', self.var)


x = X()
a = A(x)
a.publish()
print(x.d)
```

Explanation: You have to make `var` and `instance_of_X` attributes of A, see the new constructor of class A. The call to `instance_of_X` in `A.publish()` must use the attribute as well, of course.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I meant, I had some errors in my question because I didn't pay attention when writing the question and corrected them (you recognized them, thanks for that)

Comment: What I really want is that when the variable in A changes, it should get updated in the dict of X too